# AVPlayer on selected rate only once

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I've got an issue with AVPlayer. The case is: I've got one function, that sets the rate of AVPlayer

```
func applyEffect(effectNumber : Int) {
    switch effectNumber {
    case 0:
        self.AvPlayer.setRate(Float(1.0), time: kCMTimeInvalid, atHostTime: kCMTimeInvalid)
    case 1:
        self.AvPlayer.setRate(Float(1.5), time: kCMTimeInvalid, atHostTime: kCMTimeInvalid)
    case 2:
        self.AvPlayer.setRate(Float(0.5), time: kCMTimeInvalid, atHostTime: kCMTimeInvalid)
    default:
        self.AvPlayer.setRate(Float(1.0), time: kCMTimeInvalid, atHostTime: kCMTimeInvalid)
    }
}
```

For every response I download audio file into AVPlayerItem and save them as array. I've got an observer for item which calls applyEffect function if AVPlayerItem.status is changed, otherwise it applies effect immediately:

```
if AVCurrentItem.status != AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {
                AVCurrentItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
                pushMessageLoading()
            } else {
                self.applyEffect(effectNumber: currentEffect)
            }

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "status" {
        popMessageLoading()
        self.applyEffect(effectNumber: currentEffect)
        AVCurrentItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }

}
```

The AVPlayer property "automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling" is set to false during the initialisation. So, first time audio plays on a requested rate, but all times after - on rate like 1.0. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of evil is simple: I've used AVPlayer.play which equals to AVPlayer.rate = 1.0, instead of this you need to use AVPlayer.rate = *desired value*

Comment: Thank you! I was calling `.play()` immediately afterwards, overriding my rate!